# raspberry pi login fails

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi2

I configured my RPi from a NOOBS SD from scratch - works fine - then I did a reboot and suddenly it asks for a login and nothing I try works.  I didn't change anything to make this happen.  Now nothing I enter will get me past this.

This happened yesterday as well, so I reformatted the sd card - reloaded NOOBS - and started all over - you can imagine how long that takes - and now the same thing happens - what is causing this and what do I do now?

Perplexed.  Need help badly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The default login should be:

user: `pi`

password: `raspberry`

It's probably a good idea to change the password for security reasons... Especially if you plan to hook the pi up to a network.

Use [passwd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html) to do that.

Comment: Or set up a new user with your actual user name which makes it even harder to guess this.

Comment: Tried pi and raspberry - but it did not work I'm afraid. Thanks anyway.  If I cant login I wonder how can I get to terminal to use passwd?  (Tried root/root that didnt work either.)

Comment: Are you using an english keyboard? If not, try swapping y and z.

Comment: Yes, English keyboard - that was a good idea - but y and z don't affect pi and raspberry or root/root. Thanks though.

Comment: @andreas-hofmann you were on to something! Thank you!  It was a problem with the US keyboard - the Raspberry Pi UK software did not recognize my US keyboard.  I had to explicitly configure the keyboard to be US (English) - do not leave the default as GB or UK or whatever the default is.  On reboot press shift key and this allows you to reconfigure the locale and keyboard settings. (In the UK I suppose nobody has this problem.)